# REST service returning image to display in web page

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-architecture

Looking for some ideas around the best approach for doing this. I've seen examples of JAX-RS returning an image for download. However, I have a portal type app that will connect to various systems via REST apis and pull data to display a widget. Some widgets will be text, others charts, and one will be an image file that I want to then show in the browser. So, the image will be one of many things display on a page - potentially.

One thought is simply to have the service return a path to the image instead of the image itself but if there's a good way to use JAX-RS capabilities to do this, I'd like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a REST service to return an image that will be displayed on a webpage seems a bit of an overkill to me. If the image is static (i.e. always the same), there's no reason to involve services. If the image is dynamic then a service that returns its url would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. The image will be dynamic, so returning a url from that service sounds like a good idea. Thanks.